# Programmatically set view width

Tags: java, android, view

I am developing an android app. There are six main `long` variables that are displayed on-screen at any time. These are continually incremented using a timer on a separate thread. The user can watch these variables increase on screen. Each of these variables has a maximum amount.

What I'd like to do is draw a 'progress bar' for each of these variables. At the moment, I am using a `View` with a solid red colour.

Please see below for prototype:

[image]

The red bar on the left would represent a variable that has reached it's maximum amount, whilst the others are empty and the bar has a width of 0, so is invisible. Each variable is placed in a `RelativeLayout` (which represents one 'section'), which is then placed in a `LinearLayout`. At a future point I may need to add/remove some - so the solution needs to not rely on hard-coded layout positionings.

My question is how can I programmaticaly set the width of these 'progress bar's in code, whilst not hard-coding the layout co-ordinates of any of the variables?

Answer (score 0):

You should check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html ProgressBar. It will ease you with displaying the progress.

In the case of `LinearLayout` (and any `ViewGroup` for that matter) you can generate your own `LayoutParams` programatically:

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(width,height) // in px
yourLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

you will need to cast the LayoutParams to the according `ViewGroup` type.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how this works. I dont know what the `width` and `height` variables represent - the width/height of which view? I don't know how to get that information.

Comment: `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` etc. are all `ViewGroup`s that contain other Views as children, such as `ImageView` for images or `TextView` for texts. These `ViewGroup`s can also contain other `ViewGroups` as children, for example a `LinearLayout` within a `LinearLayout` or in your case a `RelativeLayout` within a `LinearLayout`. We use `LayoutParams` to describe and tell the parent views how wide and how high our views should be (hence `width` and `height` as parameters). Once we specify the dimension we apply them to the `View` we want to resize - this is in your case **yourLinearLayout**

Comment: Sorry, I think you've misunderstood - I don't want to resize the `LinearLayout` - I want to resize just the `View` within it that's acting as a progress bar.

Comment: Please phrase your questions better next time. 
You should drop the solid color View element you're using and use  `ProgressBar` as suggested. Define a minimum and maximum for the progress (e.g. min.0, max.:1000) and use `setProgress(int progress)` to update the progress and hence the width programatically. In your XML file style the ProgressBar as horizontal:  `<ProgressBar
     style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"` ...
so that it can display a progress.

Answer (score 0):

The regular way would be to use the `ProgressBar`, but if you want to use your custom view, use this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(withInPx, heightInPx);
yourView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

This assumes you use `LinearLayout`, but you should edit that if you use a different layout (i.e. `RelativeLayout`)

The `heightInPx` will be fixed in your case, but the `withInPx` you can vary, according to the progress.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how this works. I dont know what the `widthInPx` and `heightInPx` variables represent - the width/height of which view? I don't know how to get that information.